# Crear funcion en mysql sobre fechas repetidas

Tags: mysql, funciones

Necesito crear una función la cual tome las fechas de una tabla y si en esta hay 2 id que se repitan , que tome la fecha mas reciente.

Por ejemplo:

```
Usuario_ID|Video_ID|Fecha

11        |1       |2018-05-12

11        |1       |2018-05-13

11        |1       |2018-05-15
```

Y que muestre solo `"2018-05-15"`

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo del siguiente modo:

- Usando `MAX` para seleccionar la fecha máxima
- Agrupando con `GROUP BY` por usuario ¿y también por vídeo? (Esa parte no queda clara en la pregunta, pero sólo tienes que agregar a la lista del `GROUP BY` todas aquellas columnas por las que quieras agrupar).

### Agrupando por usuario y por vídeo:

```
SELECT 
     usuario_id, 
     video_id, 
     max(fecha) fecha  
 FROM videos_fechas_20180719  
 GROUP BY usuario_id,video_id;
```

**Resultado:**

```
usuario_id     video_id      fecha
--------------------------------------------------
    11             1         15.05.2018 00:00:00
```

---

### Agrupando sólo por usuario:

```
 SELECT 
     usuario_id, 
     max(fecha) fecha  
 FROM videos_fechas_20180719  
 GROUP BY usuario_id;
```

**Resultado:**

```
usuario_id     fecha
--------------------------------------------------
    11         15.05.2018 00:00:00
```

---

### Agrupando por vídeo:

```
 SELECT 
     video_id, 
     max(fecha) fecha  
 FROM videos_fechas_20180719  
 GROUP BY video_id;
```

**Resultado:**

```
video_id       fecha
--------------------------------------------------
    1          15.05.2018 00:00:00
```

Comment: excelente respuesta

Answer (score 0):

> Te propongo la siguiente respuesta, con un ejemplo para tratar de
>   guiarte y lo adaptes a tus necesidades

tengo una tabla con un id y fechas

```
MariaDB [demo]> SELECT id, fecha FROM dates;
+------+------------+
| id   | fecha      |
+------+------------+
|    1 | 2018-01-12 |
|    1 | 2018-01-11 |
|    1 | 2018-01-10 |
|    2 | 2018-01-11 |
+------+------------+
```

Posterior como puedes observar tengo tres fechas registradas con el mismo id, pero yo solo quiero la mas reciente

```
MariaDB [demo]> SELECT id, fecha FROM dates WHERE fecha = (SELECT MAX(fecha) FROM dates);
+------+------------+
| id   | fecha      |
+------+------------+
|    1 | 2018-01-12 |
+------+------------+
```

> Lo que hice fue primero seleccionar las columnas id y fecha de la
>   tabla dates pero con la clausula `WHERE` le indico que solo va a hacer
>   cuando seleccione la fecha maxima del registro; que para lograr eso
>   hago uso de una `subquery` y de la función de agregación `MAX`

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Para el caso concreto de tu query, mas o menos debería quedar de este modo

```
SELECT Usuario_ID, Video_ID, Fecha 
FROM tablaName 
WHERE Fecha = (SELECT MAX(Fecha) FROM tablaName);
```