# Limitar resultado de una consulta MYSQL con INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta de MYSQL compleja con INNER JOIN y lo que necesito es limitar el resultado por una columna. Básicamente quiero saber los empleados que son comisionistas y cuando fue la última fecha dada de alta. En movimiento de empleados se escribe un movimiento que se llama "alta de comisionista" cuando se da de alta, pero puede que suceda mas de una vez, y he aqui el problema.Paso plantear las tablas que utiliza.

**Tabla empleados**

```
CREATE TABLE `empleados` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `apellido` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `telefono` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `comisionista` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `contrasena` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `eliminado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `domicilio` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `correoelectronico` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `facebook` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `ganancia` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `nombre` (`nombre`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4
;
```

**Tabla movimiento de empleados**

```
CREATE TABLE `movimientosempleados` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fecha` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tipodemovimiento` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `numero` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `empleado` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `datonuevo` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `datoanterior` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nombrenuevo` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nombreanterior` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `usuarioqueedita` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `host` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1757
;
```

La **consulta** en cuestión es:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
empleados.id, 
nombre, 
apellido, 
comisionista, 
ganancia, 
movimientosempleados.fecha 
FROM empleados 
INNER JOIN (movimientosempleados) ON (movimientosempleados.empleado = empleados.id)  
WHERE eliminado = 0  AND comisionista = 1 AND tipodemovimiento = 'ALTA COMISIONISTA';
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <title>TablaDesconocida</title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="HeidiSQL 10.2.0.5683">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      thead tr {background-color: ActiveCaption; color: CaptionText;}
      th, td {vertical-align: top; font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 9pt; padding: 3px; }
      table, td {border: 1px solid silver;}
      table {border-collapse: collapse;}
      thead .col0 {width: 47px;}
      .col0 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col1 {width: 128px;}
      thead .col2 {width: 70px;}
      thead .col3 {width: 95px;}
      .col3 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col4 {width: 76px;}
      .col4 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col5 {width: 138px;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <table caption="TablaDesconocida (5 rows)">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col0">id</th>
          <th class="col1">nombre</th>
          <th class="col2">apellido</th>
          <th class="col3">comisionista</th>
          <th class="col4">ganancia</th>
          <th class="col5">fecha</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">-1</td>
          <td class="col1">ADMINISTRADOR</td>
          <td class="col2"></td>
          <td class="col3">1</td>
          <td class="col4">9,00</td>
          <td class="col5">2019-10-11 15:12:16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">-1</td>
          <td class="col1">ADMINISTRADOR</td>
          <td class="col2"></td>
          <td class="col3">1</td>
          <td class="col4">9,00</td>
          <td class="col5">2019-10-11 15:19:25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">0</td>
          <td class="col1">USUARIO</td>
          <td class="col2">DF</td>
          <td class="col3">1</td>
          <td class="col4">900,00</td>
          <td class="col5">2019-10-11 15:21:20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">3</td>
          <td class="col1">BERNARDO</td>
          <td class="col2"></td>
          <td class="col3">1</td>
          <td class="col4">12,00</td>
          <td class="col5">2019-10-11 14:35:19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">3</td>
          <td class="col1">BERNARDO</td>
          <td class="col2"></td>
          <td class="col3">1</td>
          <td class="col4">12,00</td>
          <td class="col5">2019-10-11 16:17:58</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>


  </body>
</html>
```

Lo que necesito seria, que se limiten los resultados por cada empleado, es decir que no se repitan los empleados pues se repiten porque hay varias veces que se realiza el movimiento 'ALTA COMISIONISTA' y ademas solo necesito obtener la ultima fecha de "alta comisionista" que seria el DATETIME de *FECHA* en *`movimientosempleados`* las anteriores no son necesarias!
Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, Gracias.

Comment: Como es la salida que queres? me suena a que queres un group by

Comment: acabo de colocar los resultados con una tabla en html para que sea bien visible

Comment: lee sobre group by.. de forma simple, usa la consulta que tenes y agrupa por todos los campos menos la fecha, y trae la maxima fecha...

Comment: Alguna posible respuesta? porque no lo entiendo, si lo he visto1!!

Comment: hay montones en el sitio, por eso no quiero agregar una mas... mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/182736/324 o aca https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/296322/324

Comment: No veo como resolveria el problema... si bien lo agrupo, pero como logro obtener por ultima fecha, un solo resultado, por empleado

Comment: group by.. lee los enlaces que te pase... y lee sobre group by...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ocupas hacer un MAX en "movimientosempleados.fecha" para que te de la ultima fecha que estas buscando y un GROUP BY para que los agrupe por empleado

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
empleados.id, 
nombre, 
apellido, 
comisionista, 
ganancia, 
MAX(movimientosempleados.fecha) 
FROM empleados 
INNER JOIN (movimientosempleados) ON (movimientosempleados.empleado = empleados.id)  
WHERE eliminado = 0  AND comisionista = 1 AND tipodemovimiento = 'ALTA COMISIONISTA' GROUP BY empleados.id;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!